# Adding current user to Symfony's submitted form

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, symfony-forms

This is part of my Post entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="post")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 private $user;
```

and from the User entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="user")
 */
 private $post;
```

my controller looks like this:

```
$post = new Post();

$form = $this->createForm('FreeCycler\UserBundle\Form\PostType', $post);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $post->setUser($this->getUser());

    // also tried this:
    //$post->setUser($this->getUser()->getId());

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($post);
    $em->flush($post);

    return $this->redirectToRoute('my_post_show', array('id' => $post->getId()));
}
```

The post gets saved to the orm but the user is empty or null.  The `$this->getUser()`, however isn't null and it's shows the user object if I dump it.

Comment: very strange, try moving the line `$post->setUser($this->getUser());` after the object creation `$post = new Post();`

Comment: I have tried this but got the same problem.

Comment: Could you show us the `Post::setUser()` method? and try to rename `name="user"` to `name="user_id"` and update your DB schema.

Comment: Are you using the `User` entity as the security user in your `SecurityUserProvider`?

Comment: In your relation between post and user, you have affect many users to one post, I think you may convert the relation.

Comment: $usr= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
$usr->getUsername();

Comment: @Emiliano, from a controller, `$this->getUser()` does the correct thing. Further, why add the call to `$usr->getUsername()` when they want the actual object, not a string. One last suggestion, be verbose in your variable naming. `$usr` is not immediately apparent or as readable as `$user`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `$post` parameter from the flush method. Doctrine won't flush the user object otherwise. Providing an entity forces Doctrine to only flush that entity and no others. Further, your relationship is bidirectional so without flushing the `$user` as well it won't work. In fact, the `flush()` method will likely have this functionality removed from Doctrine in the future.

Just do `$em->flush()`.

[Discussion of this issue on Doctrine's Github repo](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6118)